# Few errors while using password strength validator and Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I came across [article](http://passwordadvisor.com/CodeAspNet.aspx) which explains how to do password strength validation.

I am having a problem with the errors I am encountering. One error states: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match' to 'bool'` which is on line `if (Regex.Match(password, @"/\d+/",..`.

The other error says: `Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match' and 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match'` which happens on line where `AND` or `&&` statement is.

I don't understand why Regex statement isn't converting to `bool` type? And second problem is probably connected to the first one.

How can I fix this?

```
enum PasswordScore
{
    Blank = 0,
    VeryWeak = 1,
    Weak = 2,
    Medium = 3,
    Strong = 4,
    VeryStrong = 5
}

private static PasswordScore CheckStrength(string password)
{
    int score = 1;

        if (password.Length < 1)
            return PasswordScore.Blank;
        if (password.Length < 4)
            return PasswordScore.VeryWeak;

        if (password.Length >= 8)
        score++;
        if (password.Length >= 12)
            score++;
        if (Regex.Match(password, @"/\d+/", RegexOptions.ECMAScript))
            score++;
        if (Regex.Match(password, @"/[a-z]/", RegexOptions.ECMAScript) &&
            Regex.Match(password, @"/[A-Z]/", RegexOptions.ECMAScript))
            score++;
        if (Regex.Match(password, @"/.[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,-,£,(,)]/", 
            RegexOptions.ECMAScript))
            score++;

        return (PasswordScore)score;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `IsMatch`, not `Match`. `IsMatch` returns a `bool`, while `Match` returns a `Match` object which gives you more detail (captured groups, etc)

Comment: PS. Would you happened to know why my validation cannot go over score of 3?

Comment: Your regexes are wrong, you shouldn't have the '/' at the start and end. This is C#, not Javascript or Perl ;)

Answer (score 2):

Regex.Match() returns a Match object, not a boolean. You probably want to check the match.Success property, i.e.

```
var result = Regex.Match(...);
if(result.Success)
   score++;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Regex.Match` returns a `Match` type. [See this link for official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx)

You will want to change your code to:

```
if(Regex.Match(...).Success) {
    ...
}
```

Or something very similar.

Answer (score 0):

If success is all you care about, then just use the `Success` property of `Match`:

```
if (Regex.Match(password, @"/\d+/", RegexOptions.ECMAScript).Success)
```

and:

```
if (Regex.Match(password, @"/[a-z]/", RegexOptions.ECMAScript).Success && 
    Regex.Match(password, @"/[A-Z]/", RegexOptions.ECMAScript).Success)
```